# Wordpress, i dont get an excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some pages, where i filled in some text, however, in this loop i've builted, It doesn't ouput an excerpt, can figure out why ?

The script:

```
<?php   
    $pageChildren = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&number=5&hierarchical=0&child_of=16');
    if ( $pageChildren ) {
      foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
    ?>

    <div class="four columns rightbox">

        <div class="panelbox">      
             <?php echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">'. $pageChild->post_title.'</a></h2>'; ?>
            <?php 
            if (!empty($pageChild->post_excerpt)){
                echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink($pageChild->ID) . '">' . $pageChild->post_excerpt.'</a> </p> ';
            }
            ?>

        </div>   
    </div>

    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: your code is all most done so please reffered bellow comment for display post_excerpt for page content.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

or

```
    <?php the_excerpt(80); ?>
```

***80 is a word Limit.**

Comment: You don't pass arguments in the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

> **Add code in your function.php**

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

> [image]
>
> select 'excerpt' option in screenoption on page header. and add page excerpt content.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress `the excerpt` is a feature for posts, pages have the `post_excerpt` property but it is only because they share the same database fields as the posts. If you want to enable excerpt area for your pages put the following code in functions.php.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_pages_excerpts' );
function add_pages_excerpts() {
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

Now there should be 'Excerpt' area in 'Admin->New Page' ( if not, open the screen options at the right top corner and click on 'Excerpt' checkbox ).